# Functional spaces, simple inclusion

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and consider the functional spaces $L^p ([a,b])$, with p=1,2.

I need to show that  $L^2 ([a,b]) \subset L^1 ([a,b])$.

First of all, could somebody explain to me what a functional space is in this case, and what does the superscript p correspond to? Do they simply differ by how we take the norm of their elements [as indicated here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space)? Just need to get started. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a definition of $L^p$ space?

Comment: just what it would mean for the interval [a,b]. is it the space of all linear functions mapping [a,b] to some other set?

Comment: No, it is the space of all measureable function on $[a, b]$ with finite $L^p$ norm. You can find the definition of $L^p$ norm in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

$L^p([a,b])$ is the collection of Lebesgue measurable functions $f$ for which $\int_a^b |f|^p < \infty$. If you are not familiar with the theory of Lebesgue integration, then roughly you can understand $L^p([a,b])$ to be the space of functions which it makes sense to try and integrate over the bounds $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b |f(x)|^p dx < \infty$. So it is your task to show that if $\int_a^b |f|^2 < \infty$ then this implies that $\int_a^b |f| < \infty$. For a hint on this, it might be nice to break up a function $f$ as $f = f_1 + f_2$ where $f_1 = f$ when $f \leq 1$ on $[a,b]$ and $f_2 = f$ when $f > 1$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: ok thanks, will try. it just looks obvious to me that if the square of the magnitude integrated is finite then so is the |f| term, so I'm not too sure what else there is to show.

Comment: Well, you need to be a bit careful. For example, suppose that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then $$ \int_1^{\infty} f(x) dx = \infty,$$ but $$\int_1^{\infty} f(x)^2 dx = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx < \infty$$ So, here is an example where your intuition might fail. Point being that there is something special about $[a,b]$ being a set of finite length.